# No data sources found for Sub com.google.heart_rate.bpm. Error while trying to access heart rate from sensor API googlefit

Tags: android, google-fit

I am trying to access heart rate, steps and calories expended using GoogleFit sensor api. For steps, I am getting data source found but for other 2 I am getting no data source found. Also, steps data is not updated.

Really not sure how this sensor API works, does anybody know what to do?
I am following this example https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit/tree/master/BasicSensorsApi

Comment: What is the error message that you got? And please post the code that you are using with this.

Comment: also what hardware are you using?  e.g. what is the heart rate sensor you expect to get data from?